# Cleansing a Map of Its Channels

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

Suppose we have a map `m` with the following structure:

```
{:a (go "a") 
  :b "b" 
  :c "c" 
  :d (go "d")}
```

As shown, `m` has four keys, two of which contain channels.

**Question:** How could one write a *general* function (or macro?) `cleanse-map` which takes a map like `m` and outputs its channeless version (which, in this case, would be `{:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}`)?

A good helper function for this question might be as follows:

```
(defn chan? [c]
  (= (type (chan)) (type c)))
```

It also doesn't matter if the return value of `cleanse-map` (or whatever it's called) is itself a channel. i.e.:

```
`(cleanse-map m) ;=> (go {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Limitations](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/wiki/Go-Block-Best-Practices#unsupported-constructs-and-other-limitations-in-go-blocks) of `core.async` make implementation of `cleanse-map` not that straightforward. But the following one should work:

```
(defn cleanse-map [m]
  (let [entry-chs (map
                   (fn [[k v]]
                     (a/go
                       (if (chan? v)
                         [k (a/<! v)]
                         [k v])))
                   m)]
    (a/into {} (a/merge entry-chs))))
```

Basically, what is done here:

1. Each map entry is transformed to a channel which will contain this map entry. If value of map entry is a channel, it is extracted inside `go`-block within mapping function.
2. Channels with map-entries are `merge`-d into single one. After this step you have a channel with collection of map entries.
3. Channel with map entries is transformed into channel that will contain needed map (`a/into` step).

Comment: Incredibly straightforward and elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require
    [clojure.core.async :refer [go go-loop <!]]
    [clojure.core.async.impl.protocols :as p]))

(def m
  {:a (go "a")
   :b "b"
   :c "c"
   :d (go "d")
   :e "e"
   :f "f"
   :g "g"
   :h "h"
   :i "i"
   :j "j"
   :k "k"
   :l "l"
   :m "m"})

(defn readable? [x]
  (satisfies? p/ReadPort x))

(defn cleanse-map
  "Takes from each channel value in m,
   returns a single channel which will supply the fully realized m."
  [m]
  (go-loop [acc {}
            [[k v :as kv] & remaining] (seq m)]
    (if kv
      (recur (assoc acc k (if (readable? v) (<! v) v)) remaining)
      acc)))

(go (prn "***" (<! (cleanse-map m))))
```

=> "***" {:m "m", :e "e", :l "l", :k "k", :g "g", :c "c", :j "j", :h "h", :b "b", :d "d", :f "f", :i "i", :a "a"}

Comment: FWIW I'd write it with `go-loop` instead of `doseq/swap!`, but there's nothing particularly wrong with this plan.

Comment: I cannot get this to work in clojurescript. Is `ReadPort` available there?

Comment: It is but under a different namespace... `cljs.core.async.impl.protocols` https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/cljs/core/async/impl/protocols.cljs

Comment: @amalloy good idea, I changed it to a go-loop to get rid of that pesky atom